# How to take 50 samples at the same indices in two numpy arrays [batching]

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Essentially, I'm trying create batches for my NN but am struggling to do so. Here is my initial attempt:

```
  for i in range(300):
    batch_index = random.sample(range(0,100),50)
    if i % 5 == 0:
      [train_accuracy, s] = sess.run([accuracy, summ], feed_dict={x: train[batch_index], y: labels_final[batch_index]})
      writer.add_summary(s, i)
      print ("train accuracy:", train_accuracy)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: train[batch_index], y: labels_final[batch_index]})
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

EDIT: `train` was not a numpy array. Making it a numpy array made the code work.

Comment: This question have not relation with the `batch-file` tag. I suggest you to eliminate it...

Comment: What are the types of `train` and `labels_final`?

Comment: ah that did the trick, @JohanL. `train` was not a numpy array so it was giving me that error. I will edit my post and feel free to submit a response so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `list` cannot be used as index into another `list`, however it can be used as index into a `np.array`. Make sure that both `train` and `labels_final` are defined as `np.array`:s.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `random.sample` returns a list. You can't index the list `train` by a list. You must index it by an integer.